# How to edit last sent message in skype using ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, skype

I want to know is there any keyboard short cut in ubuntu to edit last sent message on skype.

Comment: mark the answer you consider correct ticking it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preas up arrow key, then the last message will start appearing in the input area, then you can edit it and press enter again. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Press up arrow. It works on my Skype instance of version 4.2.0.11 in my Ubuntu 14.04.